# testing kafka consumer and producer failed on connection

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

I have been trying to test a kafka installation and using the guide created a producer and consumer. When trying to retrieve a message I get the following error:

```
 WARN Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and 
 attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1146)
 [2014-03-04 18:01:20,628] INFO Terminate ZkClient event thread. (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread)
 [2014-03-04 18:01:21,315] INFO Opening socket connection to server kafka-test/192.xxxxxx.110:2182 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
 [2014-03-04 18:01:21,418] INFO Session: 0x0 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
 Exception in thread "main" org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 6000
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:880)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:98)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:84)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.connectZk(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:151)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:112)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:123)
    at kafka.consumer.Consumer$.create(ConsumerConnector.scala:89)
    at kafka.consumer.ConsoleConsumer$.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala:178)
    at kafka.consumer.ConsoleConsumer.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala)
 [2014-03-04 18:01:21,419] INFO EventThread shut down (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
```

Answer (score 9):

**Kafka**

Looks like you're not connecting to Zookeeper correctly. I'm not sure of your setup (multi-machine, VMs, containers) so it's hard to say what's wrong.  From the debug output I see the following line hinting at your expected Zookeeper IP:

`[2014-03-04 18:01:21,315] INFO Opening socket connection to server kafka-test/192.xxxxxx.110:2182 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)`

Kafka looks for Zookeeper at the address specified by the `zookeeper.connect` configuration property in the `$KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties` file.  Be sure to edit that before starting Kafka.  Also, try giving the actual public IP of your Zookeeper instance, not just `127.0.0.1` as that solves a lot of confusion if you're running in containers.  In your case it looks like it would be:
`zookeeper.connect=192.xxxxxx.110:2182`

Also relevant to the Kafka config if you're running on AWS or operating in a container, don't forget to update the following two configuration properties to make sure clients who connect to Kafka see the correct public IP

- `advertised.host.name`
- `advertised.port`

and Kafka sees the correct internal IP

- `host.name`
- `port`

**Zookeeper**

Zookeeper has some gotchas when setting it up as well.  On your Zookeeper instance, don't forget to edit the `server` configuration property in the `zoo.cfg` (usually in `/etc/zookeeper/conf`) file to point to the correct IP for your Zookeeper instance.  In your case probably the following:

`server.1=192.xxxxxx.110:2888:3888`

Those last two ports (2888 3888) are only needed if you're running a Zookeeper cluster (for followers to connect to the leader and Zookeeper leader election, respectively, so be sure to unblock them on firewallish things if you have multiple Zookeeper servers).

Comment: Thanks @joel-b, this lead me in the right direction.  advertised.host.name is now deprecated so you need to use the advertised.listeners for this instead.

Answer (score 7):

Check your zookeeper connection with telnet command:

> telnet 192.xxxxxx.110 2181

You probably get an error, in which case check that the process is running:

> ps -ef | grep "zookeeper.properties"

If it's not running, start it by going into kafka home directory:

> bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties &

Answer (score 4):

Something wrong with your `Zookeper` configuration. Make sure your zookeeper is up and running. The default port it runs on is **2181**

Bit more info and some `code` could be useful I believe.

Answer (score 3):

I hit the same issue and the problem was the max client connections property in zookeeper config.

if you see something like "maxClientCnxns = 20" in the config file in /etc/zookeeper/conf, comment it out and restart zookeeper.

Answer (score 1):

You may also check if the all the connections available have already been exhausted. If you are using an API to connect to ZK, make sure you free up the connection after you're done.

Answer (score 1):

I also meet the problem. When I shutdown the firewall of the zk node, it will work.